# Joomla Website looks different on Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, joomla

I am building a joomla website on my localhost since last two months, it's almost complete but yesterday when I browsed it via IE 10, the sidebar component wasn't loading properly. Actually it's a joomla Custom HTML module which loads perfectly on Chrome but wierdly on IE. I wanted to know, is there any way that I can hide that module from displaying in IE only? Any css trick or something?

Comment: Chrome likes to fix mistakes that are made in your HTML syntax. Look at your HTML for missing closing tags/tagclosers, apostrophes/quotations or anything else.

Comment: hey, i found the error.. my website loads mobile css when viewed from IE ? how can i direct my website to load the main css when visited from IE 10?

Comment: Joomla CMS doesn't detect the platform (mobile, desktop...) and loads CSS based on the platform. Joomla extension does that. Check your plugins or settings in your current template, maybe there is a bug in that extension that recognizes IE 10 as a "mobile" device and loads mobile css. You can fix that problem by yourself if you developed that extension, or ask the developer of that extension to help you fix it.

Comment: well, i have made numerous changes to the template files and it would be difficult to reach out to the developer right now.. i was thinking to direct my website to load a specific css when viewed from IE which is done adding something like this to the head tag of the HTML :

<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie7.css"  />< ![endif]-->

but i don't understand where to add code to head tag of JOOMLA WEBSITE? is there any way to do that?

Comment: You should be able to add this to templates/yourtemplate/index.php, within the head tags there.

Comment: Please tell us more about theme you using (you can provide us link to your site too (if it's already hosted somewhere outside of your computer/localserver)).

Comment: there are no head tags in the index.php file, i even tried to add head element myself, but nothing happened?

Comment: Can you search other files? Because if there is no head in index.php- it's defenetly somewhere else.

Comment: hey! i figured it out! it wasn't any problem..In my template settings, i had set my sidebar width to 22.7%..yesterday i just removed the percentage symbol "%" from the CSS and everything was fixed! THANK YOU ALL, for your comments! it was my first ever question posted on STACKOVERFLOW and i received such a warm response!

P.S - must say! CHROME is a clever browser!